# How to read 2 commands without closing the first one?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I am trying to check if username or email is taken or not. However, I want to check them separately. First username and secondly email. I am a beginner so I don't know how to write this code. When I check if a user name is taken it's okay. But after checking email it gives an error and says that close the first SQL command.

So how can I do this? How can I read 2 SQL commands without closing the first one?

```cs
// Checking if username is taken
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM kullanicilar WHERE kullaniciAdi = '<username text>' , 
yourConnection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

// Checking if email is taken
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM kullanicilar WHERE [Mail Adresi] = '<mail address text>', 
yourConnection)
var reader2 = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet. We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mcve], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Use a *Stored Procedure* and btw STOP posting code as image

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check if username is taken
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE userName=" userName , 
yourConnection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

// Check if email is taken
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE email=" email, 
yourConnection)
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i am doing it in if else statement block so this doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am not sure why are you insisting on having to find the result in two separate queries and that too without closing command for first one (if that is what you mean by 'without closing the first one') while executing the second.

To me, it seems you would like to know if the name and email already exist in the database, if so are they taken by same person (found on the same record in db) or by different persons (found on different records).

You could achieve this by following one single query. You may get multiple records back and for every record the third column match_type will clarify the type.

```
select kullaniciAdi, [Mail Adresi], 'BOTH' as match_type  from kullanicilar 
where kullaniciAdi = '<username text>' and [Mail Adresi] = '<mail address text>'
union 
select kullaniciAdi, [Mail Adresi], 'ONLY_USER' as match_type  from kullanicilar 
where kullaniciAdi = '<username text>' and [Mail Adresi] <> '<mail address text>'
union
select kullaniciAdi, [Mail Adresi], 'ONLY_MAIL' as match_type  from kullanicilar 
where kullaniciAdi <> '<username text>' and [Mail Adresi] = '<mail address text>'
```

**Note** Table and / or column names in query may have typos as it is error prone to type having looked at image.